# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound, No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

When I try to open / page, I receive that error:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>
> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/maven-archetype-webapp/] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'mvc-dispatcher'

What's wrong?

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/app-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**WEB-INF/app-context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="mvc-dispatcher" class="controller.Home"/>

</beans>
```

**controller/Home.java**

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class Home {
    String message = "Welcome to your 1st Maven Spring project !";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String simple1() {
        return "simple";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding ```<context:annotation-config/>``` in your app-context.xml

Comment: See my new WEB-INF/app-context.xml, I've added annotation-config component-scan and but problem not solved "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/maven-archetype-webapp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'"

Comment: Solved! :) See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Worked example:

---

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

---

**WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

---

**WEB-INF/jsp/simple.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>

message is <b>${message}</b>
```

---

**controller/Home.java**

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class Home {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView simple2() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("simple");

        mav.addObject("message", "woohoooo1234");
        return mav;
    }
}
```