# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound:spring

Tags: java, spring

> I am facing this problem from last one week, every application giving
>   the same message, at the end of `tomcat 8` server. I am unable to find
>   the mistake.  Please can anyone look into it. It is eating my time.

I have added Spring 3.1.1 jars, Whenever run the project the same message it is showing.

The message is :

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Project name/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Please find the code below.

```
web.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
        <display-name>Jsppagedisplay</display-name>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
            <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>


        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>


dispatcher-servlet.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="/welcome.htm">viewctrl</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="viewctrl" class="com.ctrl.ContollerClass">
        </bean>

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
    </beans>

Controller class

    package com.ctrl;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractCommandController;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public class ContollerClass extends AbstractCommandController {

        @Override
        protected ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, BindException arg3)
                throws Exception {

            ModelAndView mav = null;

            mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.addObject("person", "Varsh");
            mav.setViewName("welcome");
            return mav;
        }
    }


jsp file

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h5>Welcome to Spring</h5>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419037/org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet-nohandlerfound-no-mapping-fou

Comment: Thanks Rohit for your link. I have solved my problem. I was not giving the complete url. When i gave a complete url, the problem is solved...